# finding the missing values in a range using any scripting language - perl, python or shell script

Tags: python, perl, bash, shell

I got stuck in one problem of finding the missing values in a range and the range is also variable for the successive rows.

#### input

```
673 673 673 676 676 680
2667 2667 2668 2670 2671 2674
```

#### output should be like this

```
674 675 677 678 679
2669 2672 2673
```

This is just one part and the row values can be more also
If you need any clarification, please let me know.

Answer (score 8):

Pure bash.

Use two subshells and run a `diff`, then clean up the results.

```
diff <(cat my_range_with_holes) <(seq 1 1000) | grep '>' | cut -c 3-
```

Answer (score 6):

In Python:

```
def report_missing_numbers(f):
    for line in f:
        numbers = [int(n) for n in line.split()]
        all_numbers = set(range(numbers[0], numbers[-1]))
        missing = all_numbers - set(numbers)
        yield missing
```

**Note:** `all_numbers` is a bit of a lie, since the range excludes the final number, but since that number is guaranteed to be in the set, it doesn't affect the correctness of the algorithm.

**Note:** I removed the `[-1]` from my original answer, since `int(n)` doesn't care about the trailing `'\n'`.

Comment: Your code read just one line from the input. btw, `file` is a built-in name, don't use it as a variable.

Comment: yes, you can. btw, `.split()` without arguments doesn't break on accidental double spaces: `'1  2'.split()` -> `['1', '2']` but `'1  2'.split(' ')` -> `['1', '', '2']`. `int()` doesn't work on empty strings.

Comment: Cool! Kind thanks for returning the vote and the tip on `split()`. Sometime in the dim dark past, I used to know that, but I had forgotten.

Answer (score 5):

Perl:

```
use Modern::Perl;

for my $line (<DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @numbers     = split /\s+/, $line;
    my ($min, $max) = (sort { $a <=> $b } @numbers)[0, -1];
    my @missing     = grep { not $_ ~~ @numbers } $min .. $max;
    say join " ", @missing;
}

__DATA__
673 673 673 676 676 680
2667 2667 2668 2670 2671 2674
```

Answer (score 2):

Python:

```
for line in open("inputfile.txt"):
    vals = set(map(int, line.split()))
    minv, maxv = min(vals), max(vals)
    missing = [str(v) for v in xrange(minv + 1, maxv) if v not in vals]
    print " ".join(missing)
```

Comment: This is working fine, thanks a lot. can u explain a bit if possible.

Comment: @manu: the code is very linear. Read input (skip duplicates (why?)), convert to integers; get min, max; iterate from min to max, skip values in input, make list of strings out of them; join list to make a single string.

Comment: @bp: Converting to a set was more for the lookups in the list comprehension than for removing dupes. I admit it's not totally consequent; if there are just a few values, it doesn't really matter; if there are many, one would probably use `itertools.imap` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 2):

Sample code Using Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @missing;

while(<DATA>) {
    my @data = split (/[ ]/, $_);
    my $i = shift @data;
    foreach (@data) {
        if ($_ != ++$i) {
               push @missing, $i .. $_ - 1;
               $i = $_;
        }
    }
}

print join " ", @missing;

__DATA__
673 673 673 676 676 680
2667 2667 2668 2670 2671 2674
```

**OUTPUT**

```
674 675 677 678 679 2669 2672 2673
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby:

```
$stdin.each_line do |line|
  numbers = line.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
  missing = (numbers.min..numbers.max).to_a - numbers
  puts missing.join " "
end
```

Golf version (79 characters):

```
puts $stdin.map{|l|n=l.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i);((n.min..n.max).to_a-n).join" "}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash:

```
while read -a line ; do
  firstvalue=${line[0]}
  lastvalue=${line[${#line[@]}-1]}
  output=()
  # prepare the output array
  for (( item=firstvalue; item<=lastvalue; item++ )); do
    output[$item]=1
  done
  # unset array elements with an index from the input set
  for item in ${line[@]}; do
    unset  "output[$item]"
  done
  # echo the remaining indices
  echo -e "${!output[@]}"
done < "$infile"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl oneliner:

```
perl -anE'($a,$b)=@F[0,-1];$,=" ";@h{@F}=();say grep!exists$h{$_},$a..$b'
```

Answer (score 0):

Modification of Marcelo's solution with safe release of file handle in the event of an exception:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    numbers = [int(n) for n in f.readline()[:-1].split(' ')]
all_numbers = set(range(numbers[0], numbers[-1]))
missing = all_numbers - set(numbers)
```

This also avoids using the builtin name `file`.

Answer (score 0):

Shell solution using Bash, sort, uniq & jot (Mac OS X):

```
numbers="673 673 673 676 676 680"
numbers="2667 2667 2668 2670 2671 2674"
sorted=($(IFS=$'\n' echo "${numbers}" | tr " " '\n' | sort -u ))
low=${sorted[0]}
high=${sorted[@]: -1}
( printf "%s\n" "${sorted[@]}"; jot $((${high} - ${low} + 1)) ${low} ${high} ) | sort | uniq -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash solution:

```
cat file_of_numbers| xargs -n2 seq | sort -nu
```

Comment: This lists *all* numbers from min to max, not just the missing ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [ 673, 673, 673, 676, 676, 680]

def woo(a):
    max_, min_ = a[0:-1]
    a = set(a)

    tot = set(list(range(min_,max_+1)))
    return list( tot - a )
```

You have your list. 
Set operator is useful for comparing lists. In your case you want to find all elements that:

- are between the first value and the last one
- have been passed ( discontinuity)

Set operator generates all uniques values coming from a list

To select all values that are in `tot` but not in `a` just do `tot - a`. Just format the output as a list

if you want to conserve `a` as a list you need to use `copy()` in your function:

```
a = [ 673, 673, 673, 676, 676, 680]

def woo(a):
    max_, min_ = a[0:-1]
    a = set(a.copy())

    tot = set(list(range(min_,max_+1)))
    return list( tot - a )
```